# How does one translate "one" (as in this very question)?

Tags: перевод

How would I translate sentences like

"One should not treat others in ways that one would not like to be treated."

As far as I can tell, the russian [Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) version of this phrase uses the informal you.

But is there a literal translation without rephrasing to a you-form?

Comment: Related: http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2815/how-to-tell-a-personal-vs-impersonal-sentence

Comment: In fact there is a possibility to translate the phrase using the formal "you" (if the problem is in informal "you").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the Russian idiom is indeed using *you* (*вы/ты*) version, you could literally translate the English version using word *человек* (*person, human*):

> One should not treat others in ways that one would not like to be treated.
>   Человек не должен поступать с другими так, как он не хочет, чтобы поступали с ним.
>   (or)
>   Человек не должен относиться к другим так, как он не хочет, чтобы относились к нему.

Note that pronoun *он* (*he*) is only used because Russian word *человек* is a masculine noun - the statement applies equally to men and women.  In fact, it's exactly for this reason that English word *one* is used, rather than *man* or *woman*.  As in English, words for *человек* and *мужчина* are one and the same - *man* and hence using it in the sentence above is likely to be interpreted as addressing a male audience rather than human audience.

Finally, it's worth noting that Russian word-for-word literal translation may sound overcomplicated  due to double negatives.  Instead, you could turn it into a positive  version:

> Человек должен поступать с другими так, как он хочет, чтобы поступали с ним.
>   (or)
>   Человек должен относиться к другим так, как он хочет, чтобы относились к нему.

Comment: I think "каждый" may be better option here.

Answer (score 9):

- you can use *generic 2nd person*, which is typical for proverbs and morals. Use Singular but **without** pronoun:

  > Не относись к другим так, как не хочешь, чтобы относились к тебе.
- You can opt for infinitive impersonal sentences:

  > Не следует относиться к другим людям так, как не хочешь, чтобы относились к тебе.

Literal treatment would be *“Человек не должен относиться к другим так, как не хочет, чтобы люди относились к нему”* but it is weird and is not typical for such constructions (sounds non-native, i.e. a person knows Russian but obviously lacks experience with how people do and do not say things).

Comment: Not sure why you call it generic 2nd person, it's an imperative.

Comment: @jwalker "Как переводить "one"?" - not an imperative

Comment: @alamar It's the other one, the impersonal. What's your point?

Comment: @jwalker I merely mean that the _meaning_ is generic. You compile a sentence that *sounds* as if it were adressing the person you are speaking to but actually means that the statement is true for everyone, i.e. any hypothetical listener. Similar expressions exists without imperative: *"С кем поведёшься, от того и наберёшься", "Без труда не вытащишь рыбку из труда", "Его так просто не остановишь"*.

Comment: This is a moderately frequent usage of 2nd person which is often overlooked by materials for Russian learners. ^_^

Comment: @Shady_arc I agree, the latter example is generic personal, but the former is plain imperative, only negative. Compare: _не относись к другим так_ / _не относятся к другим так_. And this is actually another kind of impersonal construct which you might want to add to your answer.

Comment: For reference: [безличные предложения](http://goo.gl/xGvYUo), [неопределённо-личные предложения](http://goo.gl/1XoJuZ), [обобщённо-личные предложения](http://goo.gl/RUSwHU).

Comment: @jwalker It seems that from your comments **one** can make a good answer.

Comment: @Artemix Go ahead if you feel you can word it nicely. The question might need expanding, too.

Answer (score 0):

The second "one" can be translated by any suitable pronoun depending on translation of the first.
Examples: 1. Не поступай с другими так, как не хочешь, чтобы поступали с ТОБОЙ.
2. Не делай другим то, чего не желаешь СЕБЕ.